# maven build jar with dependency in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven

I understand that you do this with assembly plugin, and I have tried many descriptors but they are not working. I could not understand what the error message means.

The project architecture:

```
---sti (parent project containing a pom.xml)
-----sti-any23
-----sti-common-util
-----sti-kbsearch
-----sti-websearch
-----sti-main
```

Where **sti** is a aggregator project. Module **sti-main** depends on all the other four modules.

The parent project pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>....</groupId>
    <artifactId>sti</artifactId>
    <version>1.0alpha</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven-install-plugin.version>2.5.2</maven-install-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-source-plugin.version>2.2.1</maven-source-plugin.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.4.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    </properties>          
    <modules>
        <module>sti-any23</module>
        <module>sti-common-util</module>
        <module>sti-kbsearch</module>
        <module>sti-websearch</module>
        <module>sti-main</module>
    </modules>               
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>                
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>config/maven-assembly/module.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The descriptor 'config/maven-assembly/module.xml' looks like:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <!-- TODO: a jarjar format would be better -->
  <id>alljars</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

The error I get:

```
[WARNING] Cannot include project artifact: uk.ac.shef.dcs:sti:pom:1.0alpha; it doesn't have an associated file or directory.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sti-any23 .......................................... SUCCESS [  1.709 s]
[INFO] sti-common-util .................................... SUCCESS [  0.728 s]
[INFO] sti-kbsearch ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.213 s]
[INFO] sti-websearch ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.433 s]
[INFO] sti-main ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.855 s]
[INFO] sti ................................................ FAILURE [  0.389 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.839 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-26T19:50:53+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 75M/505M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.4:single (make-assembly) on project sti: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive alljars: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :sti
```

I also tried many other descriptors found on stackoverflow but neither did they work. I think I must have got some basic concepts wrong, but I do not know that it is.

Any suggestions please. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen usage of assembly plugin inside parent project. Your parent module is of `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. Its output is just a `pom` file. It does not make sense to have any physical artifact output besides the POM.

In my opinion you should move the assembly plugin declaration to the submodule and execute it only as part of this submodule. All other projects should be declared as dependencies to this module and from this point you should build the assembly.

Comment: Yes. Or even have a new module whose goal will be to create the assembly. Using `maven-assembly-plugin` from the parent can be used to assemble [the module binaries](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) but I would also clearly prefer to do this inside an existing module or a dedicated one.

Comment: thank you. I changed 'packaing' to 'jar', deleted 'modules' block and added the block '<dependency>
        <groupId>uk.ac.shef.dcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>sti-main</artifactId>
        <version>1.0alpha</version>
    </dependency>'. It seems to be doing the trick. Is this correct?

Comment: I agree with @Tunaki I would also prefer a dedicated module to do the work.

Comment: If you use maven-assembly-plugin from the parent it will not correctly cause the parent is executed first which means all other modules haven not been packaged. to package things always use a separate module which has the dependency to all modules you would like to package otherwise you can't be sure that all modules haven built correctly before. In particular if you use things like multithreading..